# Alfine crank 1x9 setup, spacer issue

Tags: shimano, crankset, alfine

I'm currently rebuilding a 1992 Kona Cindercone as a 1x9 commuter.
The rear spacing is 135mm and the bottom bracket shell is 68mm.

I've mounted a alfine crank on it and remove the spacer that what installed on the drive side of the crank and put it on the non drive side on the crank.

The chainline looks okay and both crank arms seem to be at the same distance with the chain stay. However I now have that massive spacer in between my crank arm and BB cup and I'm sure this is plain wrong.

I also have no experience with hollowtech cranks.

Here are some picture to illustrate my problem:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Where did the spacer come from? Why did it need to be moved from the drive to non drive side?

Comment: The spacer was originally on the drive side of the crank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution!

I've bought an alfine crankset with inner + outer chainring (FC-S501 GCx2) instead of of an alfine crankset with only the outer chainring (FC-S501 GCx1).

The problem being that the FC-S501 GCx2 is designed with a 49.2mm chainline and the FC-S501 GCx1 with a 42.7mm chainline.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you have a crank with a 'mountain' length spindle, but a 'road' Hollowtech external bottom bracket.

Hollowtech 'road' BBs only fit a 68mm shell. 'Mountain' BBs fit both 68 and 73mm shells. On a 68mm shell spacers are inserted between the shell and left and right BB bearing units so that the combined shell and spacers width is 73mm.

If you fitted a mountain BB, you would not need to have the spacer between the bearing and crank.

BTW, chain-line should not 'look right' it should *be* right. On this bike the chainring should be 47.5-50mm from the frame centerline.

Comment: Maybe I need to specify that the BB was included with the crank. I did not buy them separately. Furthermore this frame is equipped with a 68mm shell

Comment: If it is a 68mm BB shell, then you should be running a BB & Crank set for 68mm. I agree with Argenti that the Alfine is a MTB crank axle designed for a 73mm shell.